# Match two columns and get non matching column value from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables `user` and `friend_request` where I am inserting friend request using `user_id` in `friend request` table where there is `2` column `sender_id` (who sends request) and `receiver_id` (who receives request)

Now the problem starts here I want to fetch all the record from `user` and `friend_request` table and I am using join for this. I want to get the record's from `friend_request` where `session_id`=`sender_id` or `session_id`=`receiver_id` now I want if `session_id`=`sender_id` is true than I get `receiver_id` and if `session_id`=`receiver_id` is true than I want `sender_id`

Below is my tried code which is not right I know...please correct this mysql query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('friend_request');
$this->db->join('users', 'users.u_id = friend_request.sender_id');
$where = '(sender_id=' . $id . ' ' . 'or reciever_id =' . $id . ')';
$this->db->where($where);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: $where = "(sender_id=$id or reciever_id =$id)";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CodeIgniters native active record class does not support the UNION SQL command which is essentially what I believe you are trying to use.

one solution, (although its not incredibly efficient with regards to performance) would be to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select('receiver_ID as friendID')
       ->WHERE('sender_id',$id)
       ->get('friend_request');
$q1 = $this->db->last_query();

$this->db->select('sender_ID as friendID')
       ->WHERE('receiver_id',$id)
       ->get('friend_request');
$q2 = $this->db->last_query();

return $this->db->query($q1 . " UNION " . $q2)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

To match two columns and get non-matching column values from MySQL using PHP, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column1_name NOT IN (SELECT column2_name FROM table_name)
```

Here, table_name is the name of the table you want to query, column_name is the name of the column whose values you want to retrieve, column1_name is the name of the first column you want to match, and column2_name is the name of the second column you want to match.

To execute this query using PHP, you can use the following code:

```
<?php

// connect to the database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "your_database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

// check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// execute the query
$sql = "SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE column1_name NOT IN (SELECT column2_name FROM table_name)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// check if query executed successfully
if (!$result) {
    die("Error: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}

// fetch the result
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["column_name"] . "<br>";
}

// close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

This code will connect to the database, execute the query, fetch the result, and print the non-matching column values. You will need to replace your_username, your_password, your_database, table_name, column_name, column1_name, and column2_name with the appropriate values for your database and table.